# PLSQL ORA 00942 Error while executing Stored Procedure through test window "Table does not exist"

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

User Logged into a instance and have the procedure and typed Array at the user logged in level while the deparment table is at users level corresponding to its unit.

for example in plsql

prodcedure
|__ TestProc
Type
|__ id_array_input
Tables
|__ unit_details
Users
|__ Unit_Name
|__Unit_Name

where Unit_name will correspond to unit in unit_details.
and each unit_name will have separate tables under it. In this example I am taking department_details.

**TypedArray of integers**

```
create or replace type id_array_input VARRAY(20) OF NUMBER
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(id_array in id_array_input,output_data out id_array_input)

as

unit varchar2(55);

stmt varchar2(55);
count number;

    begin
        output_data:=id_array_input();

        for i in 1..id_array.count loop

        select unit_name into unit from unit_details where unit_id =id_array(i);

        stmt:="select count(*) from "|| unit||".department_details where department_name is not null';

        execute immediate stmt into count;  

        output_data.extend;
        output_data(i):=count;

        end loop;
    end;
end TESTPROC;
```

**Test Window Procedure call**

```
declare
input id_array_input;
output id_array_input;
as

input:=id_array_input(599,800);
TESTPROC(input,output);
for i in 1..output.count loop
dbms_output.put_line('-----------'||output(i)||'-------------');
end loop;
end ;
```

Comment: Not sure what this means: "while the deparment table is at users level corresponding to its unit." What are "units"?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say one of the `unit_name .department_details` tables either does not exist or the calling account does not have `select` privileges on it. Have you checked?

Comment: While executing it through sql window it's working fine. But when I try to execute it through procedure it gives me that error. Unit is a schema . Each unit has different tables under it. In my example I am trying to fetch from one of the table under a unit.

Comment: Right, normally that means you have privileges through a role, and not the direct grant required for a stored procedure.

Comment: Fixed it . By using authid current_user clause in procedure.Thanks for your time and effort.                  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(id_array in id_array_input,output_data out id_array_input)
    authid current_user 
    as

    unit varchar2(55);

    stmt varchar2(55);
    count number;

        begin
            output_data:=id_array_input();

            for i in 1..id_array.count loop

            select unit_name into unit from unit_details where unit_id =id_array(i);

            stmt:="select count(*) from "|| unit||".department_details where department_name is not null';

            execute immediate stmt into count;  

            output_data.extend;
            output_data(i):=count;

            end loop;
        end;
    end TESTPROC;
```